# How to execute native sql in oracle 12 c

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, native

I am not able to execute native sql.

I am getting below error:

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
> ORA-06512: at line 10
> 01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
> *Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
> *Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

```
sqltest := 'select create_ts  from WORKFLOW_CODES where id =' || p_id;
execute immediate (sqltest) into v_create_ts;
open p_recordset for
select v_create_ts from dual;
DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(p_recordset);

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a separate variable to store the value from an sql result to pass it on to `RETURN_RESULT` through `dual` table. The `refcursor` defined for the original table can be passed directly

```
DECLARE
     p_id          INT := 1;
     p_recordset   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
     OPEN p_recordset FOR 'select create_ts  
                       from WORKFLOW_CODES where id = ' 
     || DBMS_ASSERT.enquote_literal (p_id); -- enquote_literal to 
                                            -- prevent SQL injection
     DBMS_SQL.return_result(p_recordset);
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reply.. but this gives me error "SQL command not properly ended".

Comment: @palak : What's your Oracle version?

Comment: Oracle 12c version 1

Comment: @palak : Are you using this block of SQL or using it in some other procedure? This block works for me.

Comment: (regexp_substr(p_id,'[^,]+')); i am adding this in comparison and this is giving me only one result. I need multiple rows.

Comment: @palak: another way to state Kaushik's comment is, "Failure to clearly state your entire problem means you probably won't get the answer you wanted". Please ask another question, this time fully explaining all the issues, and reference the current question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55428302/how-to-execute-native-sql-in-oracle-12-c) in your new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
select create_ts from WORKFLOW_CODES where id =' || p_id
```

should return just one row (one `CREATE_TS` value), but it returns two (or more) rows so Oracle complains about it. Either apply another condition(s) to restrict number of rows returned, or - if ID is supposed to be *unique*, make sure it really is (for example, by removing duplicates and applying primary or unique key / index to it).

---

To illustrate what I'm saying:

```
SQL> create table workflow_codes(id number, create_ts number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into workflow_codes
  2    select 1, 100 from dual union all
  3    select 1, 200 from dual union all
  4    --
  5    select 3, 300 from dual;

3 rows created.
```

There are 2 rows for ID = 1, so it'll return an error:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_create_ts number;
  3  begin
  4    select create_ts into l_create_ts from workflow_codes where id = 1;
  5  end;
  6  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Will be OK for ID = 3:

```
SQL> l4
  4*   select create_ts into l_create_ts from workflow_codes where id = 1;
SQL> c/1/3
  4*   select create_ts into l_create_ts from workflow_codes where id = 3;
SQL> l
  1  declare
  2    l_create_ts number;
  3  begin
  4    select create_ts into l_create_ts from workflow_codes where id = 3;
  5* end;
SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```